# Rectangular border style with sharp corners

Tags: jquery, css

The border on below fiddle is curved on firefox, how can this css be updated so that its rectaungular with sharp corners ?
I've tried updating the css to "border: 1px solid #CCC !important;"

http://jsfiddle.net/3Uz7S/

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>


.pds-box {
    border: 1px solid #CCC !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override border radius, in your code both `border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius` are set to `12px`:

```
.pds-box {
    border: 1px solid #CCC !important; 
    border-radius:0 !important;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 !important;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `border-radius` tag to the CSS.

```
.pds-box {
    border: 1px solid #CCC !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}​
```