# How to retain rectangular border around button when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I select the vote button on this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3Uz7S/4/

The vote image updates to an oval shape on firefox/chrome.

How can the css be updated so that when 'vote' is selected the button retains its rectangular shape or is this even possible ?

Fiddle code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>

.pds-vote-button {
    border-radius:0 !important;     
    -webkit-border-radius:0 !important; 
}

.pds-box {    
border-radius:0 !important;     
-webkit-border-radius:0 !important; 
}
```

Comment: isn't this just a continuation of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564544/rectangular-border-style-with-sharp-corners)?

Comment: hasn't my answer solved your problem?

Comment: @haynar ive upvoted your answer, thanks. Jonathan answered initially, by one min :)

Comment: @user701254 if you'll look at time, you will see that I was the first, that's the point

Comment: @user701254 Perhaps his answer was a minute earlier. However, I explained what is happening behind the scenes that caused your problem so you know what to look for in the future, my solution is simpler than his, and I also created a jsFiddle so you could see the changes in action.

Comment: @JonathanPayne can you show me the difference between my answer and yours? where is your explanation? and creating jsFiddle doesn't make your answer better if the other things are completely same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply CSS styles also to class "pds-vote-button-load" and add `-moz-border-radius` as well

```
.pds-vote-button, .pds-vote-button-load {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It changes the class on the click to `pds-vote-button-load`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Uz7S/5/

```
.pds-vote-button-load
{
    border-radius:0 !important;     
    -webkit-border-radius:0 !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS

```
.pds-vote-button-load
{
    border-radius: 0 !important;     
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 !important; 
}
```